# Drop Dates greater a given date (keyerror)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, keyerror

I have a CSV file of following form:

| Date | Data 1 | Data 2 | ... | Data n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-02 | 123 | 222 | ... | 223 |
| 2010-01-03 | 124 | 232 | ... | 233 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-11-06 | 424 | 332 | ... | 133 |

I want to read all lines of this table into a Pandas dataframe where the column date is less than a given date, say 2010-01-05.

I just tried the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(daten["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df.drop(df["Date"] >= "2010-01-05", axis=0, inplace=True)
daten.set_index("Date", axis=0, inplace=True)
```

This gives me a key error

> KeyError: '[ True  True False ... False False False] not found in
> axis'

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method need an *Index or column labels to drop* not the rows themselves.

You can choose to keep rows that match condition:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df = df[df['Date'] < "2010-01-05"]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date  Data 1  Data 2  Data n
0 2010-01-02     123     222     223
1 2010-01-03     124     232     233
```

Or if you prefer use `drop` like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates='Date')
df.drop(df[df["Date"] >= "2010-01-05"].index, inplace=True)
```